# How to overcome a roller coaster track gap of a length of 1 or 2?

Tags: tracks

I'm creating a roller coaster MOC with a looping based on the [Creater Expert set #10261](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/roller-coaster-10261). All track pieces have a length of 8 or 16. However due to my looping I have an offset of 6. To reconnect my track with the starting point I therefore have a gap of 2 somewhere.

I played a bit and created a construction that might work (at least with 3 or more vehicles):
[image]

But I'm still not happy with this solution.

I'm wondering what might be the best way to overcome this gap?
Does there probably already exist any brick that can be used?

**Update:**

The Plate, Modified 1x2 with Bar Handles does not work, for the vehicles get stuck on the studs. However the tip with the bar was good! I found the [Pneumatic T Piece First Version (T Bar)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4697a&name=Pneumatic%20T%20Piece%20First%20Version%20(T%20Bar)&category=%5BPneumatic%5D#T=C). Together with a [Hinge Brick 1 x 2 Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3937&name=Hinge%20Brick%201%20x%202%20Base&category=%5BHinge%5D#T=C) and [Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3938&name=Hinge%20Brick%201%20x%202%20Top&category=%5BHinge%5D#T=C) this might work:

[image: Roller Coaster Track 2L]

However I do not own the Pneumatic T Piece First Version (T Bar) and cannot test it. I wonder if the hinges will not "hinge without permission"?

Comment: Assembly seen in your edit looks good in digital model, however I'm not sure if those hinges will stay in place. Their purpose is to... articulate, after all.

Comment: I very much would like to see your finished loop

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve have a look here, to get a rough idea: [link](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/15884/digital-tool-for-roller-coaster-physics)

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve here you are: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CAJLj0HBauI

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

[image: Animation]

The key element I used is the [hose nozzle (60849)](https://rebrickable.com/parts/60849/equipment-hose-nozzle-with-side-string-hole-simplified/):

[image: Element render]

I opted not to use hinges to try to create as rigid of a connection as I could. Here's the build:

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

[image: step 3]

[image: final build]

This seemed to work fine in the small amount of testing I did, but it does require a bit of careful adjusting to get everything aligned properly initially.

Comment: That's a nice solution, thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Thanks for all your contributions that helped me a lot and gave me very good pointers. Here is my final solution I will use:

I'll use [Pneumatic T Piece First Version (T Bar)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4697a&name=Pneumatic%20T%20Piece%20First%20Version%20(T%20Bar)&category=%5BPneumatic%5D#T=C) on Hinge Bricks 1 x 2 [Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3937&name=Hinge%20Brick%201%20x%202%20Base&category=%5BHinge%5D#T=C) and [Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3938&name=Hinge%20Brick%201%20x%202%20Top&category=%5BHinge%5D#T=C). To avoid unintended "hinging" of the hinge bricks I put a plate 1 x 2 and a tile 1 x 2 beside them and a [Hinge Plate 1 x 2 with 3 Fingers On Side](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2452&name=Hinge%20Plate%201%20x%202%20with%203%20Fingers%20On%20Side&category=%5BHinge%5D#T=C) on top. I found a similar brick to the Pneumatic T Piece and that worked well.

[image: My Solution]

And a detail view.

[image: Detail view]

Comment: Nice! I very much like that you found the way to build a rigid solution.

Answer (score 6):

Roller-coaster tracks are using rails in common LEGO measurement of 3.18mm. Also  referred as *bar*. There are plenty of other elements having bars of this size. I don't have exact solution, but you could give a try with either of two types of [Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Bar Handles](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=Plate,%20Modified%201%20x%202%20with%20Bar%20Handles#T=A). These have 2 studs long bars, so would fit in your gap.

[image]

Comment: The Plate, Modified 1x2 with Bar Handles does not work, for the vehicles get stuck on the studs. However the tip with the bar was good (see my updated question). If there is no better solution within the next days, I'll mark this as answer for it gave me right pointer. Thank you, Alex!

Comment: @Spock LEGO doesn't always have to be build with studs on top - check if you find a way to put pictured plate sideways aka SNOT.

Comment: Or upside-down...

Comment: @Alex I did. The roller coaster car has a a kind of pin on its bottom to get grip in the chain. On each side it has some kind of mount that hangs on the plate modified as well.
[link](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=26021&idColor=63#T=C&C=63)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution by Masao Hidaka https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fwg5YFPZ6xw using the plate, modified 1x2 with bar handles. He shows 4 ways to use this part.

[image]

Comment: Can you summarize what's in the video here?  This is close to a "link-only answer" which is strongly discouraged on StackExchange sites.  There's a good chance of the video (or other lnks) becoming stale and then there's little value left to the answer.